# Convert json to vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

i want my html to get populated with json data (json file's) which will be stored in VUEX store in object form.

ERROR: Cannot read property 'middleware' of undefined

FILER WORKING:

1.index.js file contain's store instance which will be shared accross whole app as you already know.
2.glyph.js file contain all empty object which will be filled by transformer.js
3.loader.js file contain hook for calling tansformer.js mutation
4.transformer.js is simple which is exported in store as mutations and only called by loader.js

## json file:

```
path: {
  '1': '<svg>......</svg'  
},
heroiconClass: {
  '1': 'heroicon-phone'
}
```

## default.vue:

```
<x-svg :path="glyph.path['1']" :class="glyph.heroiconClass['2']"/>
```

## CODE:

INDEX.JS

```
/*
EXTERNAL MODULE'S.
*/
// temp module's.
import __debug from 'debug' // stand alone debugger for this module.

// core module's.
import Vuex from 'vuex' // core: vuex store for data and state management.

// npm module's.
import _ from 'underscore' // npm: utility module.

/*
TRANSFORMER DATA
*/
import __glyphDataJsonModule from '~/store/json/glyph' // custom: heroicon and moon icon glyph collection.


/*
STORE OPTION'S
*/
import { loader } from './json/dataFiller/loader'
import * as getters from './json/dataFiller/getters'
import { Transformer } from './json/dataFiller/transformer'

/*
VUEX INSTANCE
*/
export const Store = new Vuex.Store({
   modules: {
     __glyphDataJsonModule
   },
   mutations: {
    Transformer
   },
   actions: {
    loader
   },
   getters
})
```

GLYPH.JS

```
/*
EXTERNAL MODULE'S.
*/
// temp module's.
import __debug from 'debug' // stand alone debugger for this module.

// npm module's.
import _ from 'underscore' // npm: utility module.

/*
EXPORT'S.
*/
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: function () {
    return {
      heroiconPath: {},
      heroiconClass: {},
      path: {},
      brand: {},
      default: {}
    }
   }
 }
```

GETTER.JS

```
export const glyph = function (state) {
 return this.state.glyph
}
```

LOADER.JS

```
/*
EXPORT'S.
*/
export const loader = function () {
  return {
    load (context) {
      context.commit('TRANSFORMER')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And whats you question?

Comment: my question is why my logic is not working as i think i have setuped vuex correctly but in reality i am always getting  Cannot read property 'middleware' of undefined
. this only happens when i mapGetters like ...mapGetters({glyph: this.$store.getters.glyphData}). please help its uregent

Answer (score 0):

Youre using `mapGetters` incorrectly.

```
// this.$store.getters.glyphData cannot be used here.
// The component is still being created so 'this' is not accessible in context of the compinent.
...mapGetters({glyph: this.$store.getters.component.
```

`__glyphDataJsonModule` doesn't have any getters defined from what you've posted. `Store` does but it isnt referencing this glyph module.

Comment: appreciated i fixed it , last problem :p error: [vuex] unknown mutation type: load. as i called this.$store.commit('load') in default.vue component beforecreate hook is it correct or is there which i have done wrong than please let me know

Comment: can you elaborate type of mutations technique ? which is used by some developer for method management by the help of string

Comment: Using constants is a common technique. The vuex documentation describes it all [under using constants for mutation types](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html).

Comment: sorry to annoy you again and again but i have already done that. is there any blog or something which you know can help me to learn more deeply what vuex wan't to say

Comment: thank's everything is working now i am getting error [vuex] unknown action type: anyname